# Flatten Binary Tree explanation

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to solve a problem about flattening Binary tree into a linked list type structure. I will write the problem description here as well

> Write a function that takes in a Binary Tree, flattens it, and returns its leftmost node. A flattened Binary Tree is a structure that's nearly identical to a Doubly Linked List (except that nodes have left and right
> pointers instead of prev and next pointers), where nodes follow the original tree's left-to-right order. Note that if the input Binary Tree happens to be a valid Binary Search Tree, the nodes in the flattened tree will be sorted. The flattening should be done in place, meaning that the original data structure should be mutated. Each BinaryTree node has an integer value, a left child node, and a right child node. Children nodes can either be BinaryTree nodes themselves or None / null.

**My code:**

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


def flattenBinaryTree(root):
    a, b = helper(root)
    return a
    pass


def helper(node):
    if node is None:
        return None, None
    if node.left is None and node.right is None:
        return node, node
    print(node.value)
    leftmostofleft = node
    rightmostofright = node
    leftmostofright = None
    rightmostofleft = None
    if node.left:
        leftmostofleft, rightmostofleft = helper(node.left)
    if node.right:
        leftmostofright, rightmostofright = helper(node.right)

    node.right = leftmostofright
    if leftmostofright:
        leftmostofright.left = node
    node.left = rightmostofleft
    if rightmostofleft:
        rightmostofleft.right = node

    return leftmostofleft, rightmostofright
```

**My issue**

The code that i put here works. but my issue what i don't understand is in these lines.

```
leftmostofleft = node
rightmostofright = node
leftmostofright = None
rightmostofleft = None
```

These are default values in case node does not have a left or does not have a right. so, i figured if node doesn't have a left child or subtree at all, the leftmostofleft would be node same with the right. but what i dont understand is why the leftmostofright and rightmostofleft has to be None. shouldn't they be node too? since the leftmost of right values of subtree is value of node too?
In short if i change the above block of code to this

```
leftmostofleft = node
rightmostofright = node
leftmostofright = node
rightmostofleft = node
```

it doesn't work. I do think it will create duplicates maybe if i did that, but I would like an explanation if possible?

**Testing code**

```
import program
import unittest


class TestProgram(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
        root = BinaryTree(1).insert([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
        root.left.right.left = BinaryTree(7)
        root.left.right.right = BinaryTree(8)
        leftMostNode = program.flattenBinaryTree(root)
        leftToRightToLeft = leftMostNode.leftToRightToLeft()
        expected = [4, 2, 7, 5, 8, 1, 6, 3, 3, 6, 1, 8, 5, 7, 2, 4]
        self.assertEqual(leftToRightToLeft, expected)


class BinaryTree(program.BinaryTree):
    def insert(self, values, i=0):
        if i >= len(values):
            return
        queue = [self]
        while len(queue) > 0:
            current = queue.pop(0)
            if current.left is None:
                current.left = BinaryTree(values[i])
                break
            queue.append(current.left)
            if current.right is None:
                current.right = BinaryTree(values[i])
                break
            queue.append(current.right)
        self.insert(values, i + 1)
        return self

    def leftToRightToLeft(self):
        nodes = []
        current = self
        while current.right is not None:
            nodes.append(current.value)
            current = current.right
        nodes.append(current.value)
        while current is not None:
            nodes.append(current.value)
            current = current.left
        return nodes
```

Comment: If that's the code you wrote yourself, how come you don't know what it does?

Comment: well i wrote it and it was not passing some cases, so i tailored it bit by bit, and before passing i had 

rightmostofleft = node
leftmostofright = node

and i changed it and it works but i am not 100% sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign `leftmostofright = node`, then when the the node does not have a right child, you would create a cycle when this assignment gets executed:

```
node.right = leftmostofright
```

That is obviously not what you want to happen. When the node has no right child, you don't want to give it a right child. In that case only `None` is the correct value for `node.right`.

Some other remarks:

- There is no need to treat a leaf node any different from other nodes. So you can just omit the `if node.left is None and node.right is None:` block.
- When a node has no left child, you don't really need to assign to `node.left`. Same for when there is no right child.
- You can do without `leftmostofright` and `rightmostofleft`, by assigning those references *directly* to `node.left` and `node.right` respectively.

And so your `helper` code could be reduced to just this:

```
def helper(node):
    leftmost = node
    rightmost = node
    if node and node.left:
        leftmost, node.left = helper(node.left)
        node.left.right = node
    if node and node.right:
        node.right, rightmost = helper(node.right)
        node.right.left = node
    return leftmost, rightmost
```

Comment: after a long overthinking, makes sense. thank you for the explanation. leftmostofright and rightmostofleft are for attachments and they can't have node. they have to be None.